# An $A$-algebra $B$ carries the same data as a ring map $A \rightarrow B$

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules

I'm trying to show that an $A$-algebra $B$ has the same data as a ring map $\phi: A\rightarrow B$.

An $A$-algebra $X$ is an $A$-module $B$ that comes equipped with a bilinear operator $\times_B: B \times B \rightarrow B$. So to spell out fully, we have an abelian group $(B, +_B, 0_B)$ that is equipped with a bilinear multiplication: $\times_B$. We then have that $B$ is also a module on $A$, so there is an action $\curvearrowright: A \times B \rightarrow A$ which obeys the module axioms.

**Ring map gives $A$-algebra**:

Since we have a ring map, this means that $(A, +_A, \times_A, 0_A, 1_A)$ and $(B, +_B, \times_B, 0_B, 1_B)$ are both rings.

Given a ring map $\phi: A \rightarrow B$, we can give $B$ an $A$-algebra structure by defining the module action to be $a \curvearrowright b \equiv \phi(a) \times_B b$. The biliniear operator on $B$ is simply the ring multiplication $\times_B$.

**$A$-algebra gives ring map**:

Since we have an $A$-algebra, $(A, +_A, \times_A, 0_A, 1_A)$ is a ring and $(B, +_B, 0_B)$ is an abelian group. The $A$-module data is given by an action $\curvearrowright: A \times B \rightarrow B$, and the algebra / bilinear product data on $B$ is given by $\times_B: B \times B \rightarrow B$.

I try to define the ring map $\phi: A \rightarrow B$. However, the first problem: I don't know that $B$ is a ring with unity! So let's assume  that the algebra is unital. Then we get a ring $(B, +_B, \times_B, 0_B, 1_B)$. Given this, let's define $\phi(a) \equiv a \curvearrowright 1_B$.

This lets us prove:

$$
\phi(a +_A a') = (a +_A a') \curvearrowright 1_B = (a\curvearrowright 1_B) +_B (a' \curvearrowright 1_B) = \phi(a) +_B \phi(a')
$$

Next, we need to show that $\phi(ab) = \phi(a) \phi(b)$. I get stuck here:

$$
\phi(ab) = (ab) \curvearrowright 1_B = a \curvearrowright (b \curvearrowright 1_B) \\
\phi(a) \times_B \phi(b) = (a \curvearrowright 1_B) \times_B (b \curvearrowright 1_B) \\
$$

I have no idea how to proceed. I need some relationship between $\curvearrowright$ and $\times_B$ which I do not possess. I'd appreciate some help in learning how to continue the proof.

Comment: It would help if you write down explicitly your definition of $A$-algebra. For some people (like me), an $A$ algebra is *by definition* a ring $B$ endowed with a ring homomorphism $A\rightarrow B$ (everything being commutative).

Comment: Updated. This is approximate, since I'm not sure what the textbook has in mind, this is the first time I've seen the words "A-algebra" in the book. I think it takes it as a pre-requisite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the definition in your textbook means that the operator $\times_B:B\times B\rightarrow B$ is $A$-bilinear, i.e. it is $A$-linear on both operands.

Also, it is probably also assumed that a multiplicative unit $1_B$ exists.

This then gives what you want to prove:
$$\phi(ab) = (ab)\curvearrowright 1_B = (ab)\curvearrowright (1_B \times_B 1_B) = (a\curvearrowright 1_B)\times_B (b \curvearrowright 1_B) = \phi(a) \times_B \phi(b),$$
where the third equality uses the bilinearity.

Comment: Am I right in understanding that (i) $A$-bilinearity means that $(a \curvearrowright b) \times_B b' = a \curvearrowright (b \times_B b')$, and similarly for the right hand side of $\times_B$? Also, (ii) does $A$-bilinearity also imply $B$-bilinearity?

Comment: Your understanding of $A$-bilinearity is correct. It doesn't always imply $B$-bilinearity. $B$ can be non-commutative or even non-associative.